# How to add custom property to asp.net custom server control?

Tags: asp.net, properties, custom-server-controls

I have created an asp.net custom control and now want to pass some values to it from the page which will use the control.Is there any way i can add my own property to the control (like Text property is present for a Label control) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a class. Add a public property to it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming ASP.NET 3.5+ just create properties

> public string YourProperty {get; set;}

Would be declarative on the control

Answer (score 1):

Adding a property to a custom control in asp.net is no different than adding a property on any class in C# (for instance).

```
public class Custom : Control
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just add it as public property, then it should be useable for your needs.